# How do I prevent mplayer from resuming/playing when entering or leaving fullscreen?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, fullscreen, mplayer

When I press `f` to toggle the full screen mode of mplayer, mplayer immediately starts playing. This is not the behavior I want.

I searched the man page and couldn't find anything useful. The only thing I could find was the [hidden setting](http://blog.mplayerx.org/blog/2013/02/01/hidden-settings/) `PlayWhenEnterFullScrn` of `MPlayerX`, a mplayer frontend on OS X .

Unfortunately after checking the [MPlayerX source](https://github.com/niltsh/MPlayerX/blob/15690421563e4c2d60a790d7c02d942e48822c8a/MPlayerX/ControlUIView.m#L761), it does not use an existing feature of `mplayer`.

Is there any way to achieve the indented behavior with `mplayer` (or any fork like `mpv` for that matter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behaviour from the MPlayer commandline by using the `-pausing` option. This worked well on my system with the following syntax:

```
mplayer -vo xv -pausing 2 input.mp4
```

When testing I noted that this syntax also worked well with `-vo x11` but unfortunately *failed* with my preferred accelerated video output: `-vo vdpau`.

All available options for `-pausing` can be seen in the MPlayer man pages:

```
-pausing <0-3> (MPlayer only)

Specifies the default pausing behaviour of commands, i.e. whether MPlayer will
continue playback or stay paused after the command has finished. See
DOCS/tech/slave.txt for further details.

  0 resume  
  1 pause (pausing)
  2 keep the paused / playing status (pausing_keep)
  3 toggle the paused / playing status (pausing_toggle)
  4 pause without frame step (experimental) (pausing_keep_force)
```

The option `4` would have been ideal as it promises to eliminate the slight frame *step* seen with the other options but this failed completely on my system...

**References:**

- [MPlayer man pages...](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html)